# Proving the 100 Prisoners and a lightbulb with Dafny

Tags: formal-verification, loop-invariant, dafny

Consider the standard strategy to solve the [100 prisoners and a lightbulb](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116340/100-prisoners-and-a-lightbulb) problem. Here's my attempt to model it in Dafny:

```
method strategy<T>(P: set<T>, Special: T) returns (count: int)
  requires |P| > 1 && Special in P
  ensures count == (|P| - 1)
  decreases *
{
  count := 0;
  var I := {};
  var S := {};
  var switch := false;

  while (count < (|P|-1)) 
    invariant count <= (|P|-1) 
    invariant count > 0 ==> Special in I
    invariant Special !in S && S < P && S <= I && I <= P 
    decreases *
  { 
    var c :| c in P;
    I := I + {c};

    if c == Special {
      if switch == true {
        switch := false;
        count := count + 1;
      }
    } else {
      if c !in S && switch == false {
        S := S + {c};
        switch := true;
      }
    }
  }  

  assert(I == P);  
}
```

It fails, however, to prove that in the end `I == P`. Why? I probably need to strengthen the loop invariant even further, but can't imagine where to start from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/NAojq) is one way to do it.

I had to add one conceptually key loop invariant and one not-so-conceptually-key-but-helpful-to-Dafny lemma.

You need a loop invariant that connects `count` to the various sets somehow. Otherwise the fact that `count == |P| - 1` after the loop isn't very useful. I chose to use

```
if switch then |S| == count + 1 else |S| == count
```

which connects `count` to the cardinality of `S`. (I think of `S` as the set of prisoners counted by The Counter.) When the light is off, `count` is up to date (ie, `|S| == count`). But when the light is on, we are waiting for The Counter to notice and update the count, so it is one behind (ie, `|S| == count + 1`).

With this loop invariant, we can now argue that `I == P` after the loop. By one of your other loop invariants, we already know `I <= P`. So it suffices to prove `P <= I`. Suppose instead that `I < P`. Then we have `S < I < P`. But by the loop exit condition, we also have `|S| == |P| - 1`. This is impossible.

The only wrinkle is that Dafny can't directly connect the subset relationships with the cardinality relationships, so we have to help it out. I proved a lemma, `CardinalitySubset`, which, given sets `A` and `B` such that `A < B`, it follows that `|A| < |B|`. The proof goes by induction on `B`, and is relatively straightforward. Calling it with the relevant sets finishes the main proof.

---

As an aside, I looked a little bit into why Dafny doesn't directly connect subset relationships to cardinality relationships. In Dafny's axioms about sets, I found a [commented out axiom](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/b971c88eff9ed9415bc713b4b14a4dc6cb0bcdcf/Binaries/DafnyPrelude.bpl#L552-L554) relating cardinality with subsets. (Admittedly, this axiom is about the non-strict subset relation, but by uncommenting this axiom, I was able to get a version of the proof to go through without additional lemmas, so it would be sufficient.) Tracing it back to [why the axiom was commented out](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/commit/10f618e342f7c916ef2c38764944d1d76c9f46bb), it seems like the solver was using it too much even when it wasn't relevant, which slowed things down.

It ends up not being a huge deal because we can prove what we need by induction, but it's an interesting tidbit.